# Python word counter for all files in the current directory

Tags: python, file, console

I wrote a simple command-line script to count all words in all documents (of the supported formats) in the current directory. Currently it supports TXT, DOCX, XLSX, and PDF formats and has been satisfactorily tested with them. As a freelance translator and content writer, this script provides me with an excellent tool, to quickly evaluate the scope of large projects by simply "dropping" the script into a directory and running it from PowerShell/Terminal.

Currently tested in Windows 10 only.

What do you think of this script? What should I improve?

```
import os
import openpyxl
import platform
import docx2txt
import PyPDF2


def current_dir():
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        directory = os.listdir(".\\")
    else:
        directory = os.getcwd()
    return directory


def excel_counter(filename):
    count = 0
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for sheet in wb:
        for row in sheet:
            for cell in row:
                text = str(cell.value)
                if text != "None":
                    word_list = text.split()
                    count += len(word_list)
    return count


def pdf_counter(filename):
    pdf_word_count = 0
    pdfFileObj = open(filename, "rb")
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    number_of_pages = pdfReader.getNumPages() - 1
    for page in range(0, number_of_pages + 1):
        page_contents = pdfReader.getPage(page - 1)
        raw_text = page_contents.extractText()
        text = raw_text.encode('utf-8')
        page_word_count = len(text.split())
        pdf_word_count += page_word_count
    return pdf_word_count


def main():
    word_count = 0
    print(f"Current Directory: {os.getcwd()}")
    for file in current_dir():
        file_name_list = os.path.splitext(file)
        extension = file_name_list[1]
        if extension == ".xlsx":
            current_count = excel_counter(file)
            print(f"{file} {current_count}")
            word_count += current_count
        if extension == ".docx":
            text = docx2txt.process(file)
            current_count = len(text.split())
            print(f"{file} {current_count}")
            word_count += current_count
        if extension == ".txt":
            f = open(file, "r")
            text = f.read()
            current_count = len(text.split())
            print(f"{file} {current_count}")
            word_count += current_count
        if extension == ".pdf":
            pdf_word_count = pdf_counter(file)
            print(f"{file} {pdf_word_count}")
            word_count += pdf_word_count
        else:
            pass
    print(f"Total: {word_count}")


main()
```

Comment: What do you consider to be a word?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using pathlib and Path objects instead of os, and you should use a context manager when manipulating files (e.g. `with open("file.txt", "r") as file: ...`). You also have a lot of repeating code when you're checking extensions, and you keep checking the rest of the if statements even if it's matched an earlier one. And the final `else: pass` does literally nothing so just remove that.

You could also do something about your nested for loops for sheet, row and cell (you'd typically use zip or itertools.product then) but this is kind of readable and nice so I'm not sure it's worth the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Refactor the code so each file type gets it's own function for counting the words like `excel_counter()` and `pdf_counter()`.  Then use a dict to map file extensions to the functions.

Something like:

```
def docx_counter(file):
    text = docx2txt.process(file)
    return len(text.split())

def txt_counter(file):
    f = open(file, "r")
    text = f.read()
    return len(text.split())

def unknown_counter(file):
    print(f"Don't know how to process {file}.")
    return 0


def main():
    word_count = 0

    print(f"Current Directory: {os.getcwd()}")

    counter = {
         ".xlsx":excel_counter,
         ".docx":docx_counter,
         ".txt":txt_counter,
         ".pdf":pdf_counter
         }

    for file in current_dir():
        file_name_list = os.path.splitext(file)
        extension = file_name_list[1]

        current_count = counter.get(extension, null_counter)(file)
        print(f"{file} {current_count}")
        word_count += current_count

    print(f"Total: {word_count}")
```

Comment: Redefining the `counter` dictionary for every file seems like a waste. Jut move it out of the loop. And it seems like you renamed `null_counter` to `unknown_counter`,  but forgot to update the `counter.get` line.

Comment: @Graipher, You're absolutely correct--revised.  It could be a global constant as well, or built dynamically by searching the module for functions with names like "*_counter".